# My prefix gives a lesson; my infix makes a sound

Tags: riddle, poetry

> My prefix gives a lesson 
>   My infix makes a sound 
>   My suffix is a tunnel 
>   to keep smoke off the ground
>
> For a kingdom that's worthy 
>   Though it stands tall 
>   If it does not heed this message 
>   It is sure to fall

Who/what am I?

Comment: This is my first try at compiling a Riley riddle. Hope you like it!

Comment: It's *teacherbangchimney*, obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Parabellum

My prefix gives a lesson

> Parabel sounds like "parable" - a simple story used to illustrate a moral lesson. (this is the loosest part of the answer)

My infix makes a sound

> Bell

My suffix is a tunnel
to keep smoke off the ground

> Lum (another word for a chimney)

For a kingdom that's worthy
Though it stands tall
If it does not heed this message
It is sure to fall

> "Si vis pacem, para bellum" is a Latin adage translated as "If you want peace, prepare for war". Particularly, the "para bellum" part means "prepare for war", a particularly strong message for our kingdom.

Note

> Parabellum is also the name of a [firearm cartridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9%C3%9719mm_Parabellum)

Comment: Excellent! That didn’t take long for you. I even had the hints set up :)

Comment: The last note mentioned in your answer was also to be posted as a hint!